# Auto Aim Bow code, Teleport Command Minecraft 1.13

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

With Minecraft's new patch, I cannot simply copy down command block code for creating a mechanism that will rotate an arrow towards the nearest player. I have been testing this out in single player with a repeating non Redstone activated command block with the code of:

```
teleport @e[type=minecraft:arrow] ^ ^ ^ facing entity @p feet
```

The teleport feature is new to this patch (to my understanding) so please help me understand if I'm doing this right.

Answer (score 1):

`teleport` works relative to the executioner, no matter if `~ ~ ~` or `^ ^ ^`.

So you want:

```
/execute as @e[type=minecraft:arrow] at @s run teleport @s ~ ~ ~ facing entity @p
```

Note that this will neither redirect the arrow towards you (it has a `Motion` tag and to change that properly you need sinus calculation), nor will it actually rotate the tip of the arrow towards you, because facing directions of arrows are always a bit weird.